# Jooq INSERT...ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE...RETURNING doesn't return value or catch the database exception

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, postgresql-10

Using Jooq 3.13.5, Postgresql 10.

The expectation is that the insert query will insert the row into the database table if it doesn't already exist and return the *id* column regardless.

Table:

CREATE descriptor_table (
id serial primary key,
name text unique
);

Working SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO descriptor_table (name)
  VALUES('a name')
ON CONFLICT("name")
  DO UPDATE SET name=EXCLUDED.name
RETURNING id;
```

Java code:

```
DSLContext dsl = jooqProvider.getDSLContext();
dsl.transaction(configuration -> {
  MyRecord                                                             
      idValue =                                                              
      DSL.using(configuration)                                                 
         .insertInto(DESCRIPTOR_TABLE)                                               
         .set(DESCRIPTOR_TABLE.NAME, "a name")                            
         .onConflict(Keys.DESCRIPTOR_TABLE_NAME_KEY.getFieldsArray())                
         .doUpdate()                                                           
         .set(DESCRIPTOR_TABLE.NAME, "EXCLUDED.name")                                
         .where(DESCRIPTOR_TABLE.NAME.eq("a name")))                       
         .returning(DESCRIPTOR_TABLE.ID)                                             
         .fetchOne();
}
```

The resulting MyRecord value is null.

Answer (score 3):

Your string `"EXCLUDED.name"` is just a string bind variable, not an expression. It's no different from setting the `NAME` column to e.g. `"Mike"` or like your other bind variable `"a name"`.

If you want a [plain SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) expression, use [`DSL.field(String, DataType)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType)) or a similar overload:

```java
.set(DESCRIPTOR_TABLE.NAME, field("EXCLUDED.name", DESCRIPTOR_TABLE.NAME.getDataType()))
```

Note that your jOOQ query has a `where()` clause, unlike your SQL query...